# FQL using facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying to create an android application using the facebook android SDK (http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). I'm trying to figure out if I will be able to use FQL using this SDK. If anyone has any experiences in this regard, please let me know.

FQL can apparently be used using https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY, the facebook android SDK however doesn't seem to support this.

Thanks;

Answer (score 8):

This is probably a better way than mentioned. Using the current version of the API you don't need to manually add the access token or use Util.openURL.

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "fql.query");
        params.putString("query", "SELECT name, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY name");
        String response = $fb.request(params);
        response = "{\"data\":" + response + "}";

        JSONObject json = Util.parseJson( response );
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray( "data" );

        for ( int i = 0, size = data.length(); i < size; i++ ){
            JSONObject friend = data.getJSONObject( i );

            String id = friend.getString( "uid" );
            String name = friend.getString( "name" );
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code using the suggested patch:

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("access_token", facebookManager.mFacebook.getAccessToken());
    b.putString("query", "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()");

    try {
        String myResult = Util.openUrl("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query", "GET", b);
            Log.i("MyResult", myResult);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

What you really need to do is using a `graphPathRequest`. Within android SDK, it is already provided 2 versions of it one is quick execute method. Another is to make a request and modify that request before you call execute on such request object. My method use later version.

In case you are within `FacebookActivity`, simply call:

```java
Request r = new Request.newGraphPathRequest(getSession(), "fql", 
    new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
           // your FQL result will be stored in response.getGraphObject()
           Log.d("result", response.toString());
        }
    }
);
r.getParameters().putString("q", YOUR_QUERY_HERE);
r.executeAsync();
```

Hope this helps.

Note that I'm using AndroidSDK 3.0

Comment: Request is missing in SdK 4.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Android Facebook SDK doesn't URL encode the params for the old REST api. So when you send a big FQL query it can't handle all the spaces and special characters. I'll probably put a fork up on github that fixes this, but in the meantime you can change line 26 in com.facebook.android.Util to:

```
sb.append(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(parameters.getString(key)));
```

Notice the URLEncoder call there. That's actually the deprecated version of the method but it will work fine for now, I'll include the correct one when I push to github.