# How to send a FQL query with the new Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk

I've been searching over the [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/android) website looking for a way to use the new SDK and send FQL queries but it seems like everything has changed and the documentation is talking about all sorts of other ways to request `me` or `friends` but not specific information such as are those friends using my app or not?

so I wrote down a nice FQL query

```
select uid, name, pic_square, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

and now, all I have to do is run it.

Since the only requests that seem good for returning a list of friends are `Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync` and `Request.newMyFriendsRequest` I assumed they'ed be my friends, but both don't allow the fine tuning of a FQL query.

how can I send a query and get back a list of friends or at least a `JSONArray`?

the Hackbook - FQL Query tutorial is using the old version of the SDK and I don't know what to do.

***UPDATE:***

I added these lines of code thinking it will let me create this query:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // SOME CODE
    this.openSession();
}

protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Session activeSession = getSession().getActiveSession();
        facebook.setAccessToken(activeSession.getAccessToken());
        facebook.setAccessExpires(activeSession.getExpirationDate().getTime());

        Request req = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(activeSession, new GraphUserListCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                System.out.println(response.toString());

            }
        });
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "fql.query");
        params.putString("query", "select uid, name, pic_square, is_app_user " + "from user where uid in "
                + "(select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())");
        req.setParameters(params);
        Request.executeBatchAsync(req);

    }
}
```

I did this, thinking it will edit the request and add the information I want but I got this error:

```
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.sample.facebook.to.db.MainActivity$1.onCompleted(MainActivity.java:62)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.facebook.Request$2.onCompleted(Request.java:269)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1197)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
10-31 09:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
String fqlQuery = "select uid, name, pic_square, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", fqlQuery);

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Request request = new Request(session, 
    "/fql", 
    params, 
    HttpMethod.GET, 
    new Request.Callback(){ 
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got results: " + response.toString());
    }
});
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

You're basically making a Graph API request to the "/fql" endpoint with your query passed in to the "q" parameter.

Comment: thanks a bunch!
I was just not getting how to use the new format of `Graph-API` with this SDK...

Comment: It's really working but I have question, why it doesn't return all my friends? just a few.

Comment: just like using the GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest this will only return the friends that have installed your app as well, not all friends.

Comment: Session class is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method

```
void a(){
         String fqlQuery = "{" +
                 "'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25'," +
                 "'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
                 "(SELECT uid2 FROM #friends)'," +
                 "}";
           Bundle params = new Bundle();
           params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
           Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
           Request request = new Request(session,
               "/fql",                         
               params,                         
               HttpMethod.GET,                 
               new Request.Callback(){         
                   public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                       Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());
                   }                  
           }); 
           Request.executeBatchAsync(request);    
    }
```

Comment: Session class is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a thread that discusses this: [FQL using facebook android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729290/fql-using-facebook-android-sdk)

You can also just issue a Graph API call with this format: graph.facebook.com/fql?q=QUERY

So in your case it can look like: graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select uid, name, pic_square, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())

EDIT:
It seems that a sample of this functionality lives in the sample app "Hackbook"
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/FQLQuery.java

Most notably, this block of code (line 61):

```
String query = mFQLQuery.getText().toString();
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query", query);
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, new FQLRequestListener());
```

Comment: saw this, the only problem is that since the new SDK I have no idea how to do this. it's like everything has changed

Comment: @Samantha, hackbook is using the old SDK, the new one doesn't even have the `Utility` class, that was the basis for the whole question