# How to find a specific facebook groups in api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

For an app we are developing, I want to be able to search within a users groups. Only way to do this via facebook API I found out so far is to load all groups and then do some comparison inside the app.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/groups?locale=de_DE

The search API returns all matches, but I can´t only see the ones that I "liked" already. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2?locale=de_DE#search
Is there different way, maybe with FQL?

Comment: Basically I got the answer here, how to use fql in graph API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145284/how-to-send-a-fql-query-with-the-new-android-sdk
I will try to get this to work with the answer Tobi provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the "normal" Graph API, you cannot specify a search criteria. The `/search` endpoint is no match for you, because it doesn't perform a search on **one** user, but for **all**.

With FQL, you could theoretically use the `strpos()` function on a query on the `group` and `group_member` tables:

```
select gid, name from group where gid in (select gid from group_member where uid=me()) and strpos(name, 'Facebook') >= 0
```

Will give you all your groups containing "Facebook" in their name. Keep in mind that you need a v2.0 app to be able to use FQL.