# How to execute graph-api Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I can run this at facebook Graph API Explorer to get user id, User name, recent status, and profile picture,

```
/8794851923?fields=id,name,statuses,picture
```

how to execute that in android using Facebook-SDK and get the result ?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105904/1549865), but it's deprecated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking a look at facebook sample SDK, I got this :

```
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
     params.putString("fields", "id,name,statuses");

 final String requestId = "154727011315956";

 Request request = new Request(session, requestId, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
      public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if(error!=null){
                 Log.e("Error", error.getErrorMessage());
                 }

            }
        });

    Request.executeAndWait(request);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do something like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

What would the Bundle params look like?

Comment: can we get birthday from this

Comment: What is the exact package of `Request` class? I include android facebook sdk into the android studio project but it is saying `cannot resolve symbol Request'

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal, I cant remember, also it's an old code with old facebook api, you can look into the facebook api documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

Comment: Thanks @barikatul now as for facebook SDF 4.0.1 `Request` class is replaced by `GraphRequest` class.

Answer (score 0):

> The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's
>   social graph. It's a low-level HTTP-based API that you can use to
>   query data, post new stories, upload photos and a variety of other
>   tasks that an app might need to do. This guide will teach you how to
>   accomplish all these things in the Graph API.

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
                    System.out.println("Response::" + String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));

        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Here,

**AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() >>** Login user access-token

**/me>>** Developer's own profile info

here also applied id/name of user/page to get that info
like: ***/joshuatreemusicfestival/posts/***

**null>>** here pass parameters of actual getting which type of info of user/page like:

```
Bundle param = new Bundle();
        param.putString("fields", "message,created_time,id,full_picture,status_type,source,comments.summary(true),likes.summary(true)");
```

*param* replace *null*

**HttpMethod.GET>>** Method of request **[GET, POST, DELETE]**

At last **onCompleted()** calling & getting response which you want...!!!

[For referance](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5)